# Extend subclass with callback function to superclass

Tags: javascript

I have two classes:

1. Socket baseclass - Which handles basic operations for a socket connection
2. Socket subclass - Which should apply specific operations i.e. when a message is received

In my application, I have multiple socket connections that I may open - Hence why I don't want to repeat all the logic for opening and closing my socket connection.

Similarly, when I receive a message on one of the connections I may handle the messages differently, depending on what connection I have opened.

Therefore, I came up with the following solution:

```
class SocketBase {
    constructor(messageHandler, errorHandler) {
        this.messageHandler = messageHandler
        this.errorHandler = errorHandler
    }
    openSocket = async () => {
        //Logic for opening up socket

        //Subscribe to socket events
        .subscribe(
            (x) => this.messageHandler(x),
            (err) => this.errorHandler(err),
            () => console.log("Observer got a complete notification"),
        )
   }
}
```

As you can see, I want to pass two callback functions to my above super-class - Respectively one for handling incoming messages, and another for handling eventual error events.

My sub-class looks as follows:

```
class Sub extends SocketBase {
    constructor(link) {
        super(this.messageHandler, this.errorHandler)
    }
    errorHandler = (err) => {
        //some logic
    }
    messageHandler = (message) => {
        //some logic
    }

}
```

Since the incoming messages are events, I thought passing a callback function to the super-class made sense. However, I realize that my sonarlint is complaining.

i.e.

> 'this' is not allowed before 'super()'.sonarlint(javascript:S3854)

It is however possible for me to define the callback function in my constructor arguments as follows:

```
super(function(message){console.log(message)}, function(error){console.log(error)})
```

Ofcause this is not what I want, for obvious reasons the above solution may get very messy.

Another solution would be for me to construct my base-class, but that would give me some undesired issues as well.. For example, I would have to do as follows:

```
this.socketBase = new SocketBase(this.messageHandler, this.errorHandler)

//Open socket (Not pretty) 
openSocket = () => {
    this.socketBase.openSocket() 
}
```

Conclusively, I want to understand how I should approach this problem?

Comment: `super(function(message){console.log(message)}, function(error){console.log(error)})` if you don't want to declare your functions inside the `super()` parameters, use constants before that.

Comment: FWIW - OOP design concepts of "_is a_" vs. "_has a_" should be considered here. The relationship Sub-is-a-SocketBase doesn't make sense in the context of your question - Sub-has-a-SocketBase is a better fit. This also allows composition rather than inheritance and depending on the bigger picture, SocketBase could become an dependency injected resource. But, like I said, FWIW.

Comment: Is `openSocket` the only method of `SocketBase`? If so, you may want to reconsider using a `class` here at all. A simple `function` to which you pass the two handlers as arguments might be much simpler.

Comment: Why are you passing the functions in the first place?  You can simply define them in the subclass, then call them in the super class using `this.errorHandler`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your code example, there is no need to pass the functions, at all:

```js
class SocketBase {
    openSocket = async () => {
        //Logic for opening up socket

        //Subscribe to socket events
        .subscribe(
            (x) => this.messageHandler(x),
            (err) => this.errorHandler(err),
            () => console.log("Observer got a complete notification"),
        )
   }
}

class Sub extends SocketBase {
    constructor(link) {
        super();
        //  do whatever you need to do with `link` parameter
    }
    errorHandler = (err) => {
        //some logic
    }
    messageHandler = (message) => {
        //some logic
    }
}
```

If for whatever strange reason you need the passing to the super class, here you go.

You can define constants and pass those to `super`, and by calling super, you already assign those to your instance `this`.

```js
class Sub extends SocketBase {
  constructor(link) {
    const errorHandler = (err) => {
      // errorHandler Code here
    }
    const messageHandler = (msg) => {
      // messageHandler Code here
    }
    super(messageHandler, errorHandler)
  }
}
```

You can also work with closures here, but in that case remember to use regular functions and bind them in the superclass:

```js
function errorHandler(err) {
  // errorHandler Code here
}
function messageHandler(msg) {
  // messageHandler Code here
}

class Sub extends SocketBase {
  constructor(link) {
    super(messageHandler, errorHandler);
  }
}

class SocketBase {
  constructor(messageHandler, errorHandler) {
    this.messageHandler = messageHandler.bind(this);
    this.errorHandler = errorHandler.bind(this);
  }
}
```

Comment: Aha, gocha! Thanks alot. However, I'm curious - Is it "okay" to define the functions in my subclass and call them from my super class? I mean, It's easy to mess up and make a typo in my func declaration - causing my event to throw an error.

Comment: Calling methods defined in the sub-class is a common pattern called Template Method: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern

Comment: However, before you get too excited about Template Method, using composition is usually easier to maintain (and compose). For example, `class Operation { contructor(socket) { ...`, and you use `socket` there, setting the handlers.

Comment: *Is it "okay" to define the functions in my subclass and call them from my super class?* That is the basic OOP way, it's intended to be used like that.